Не могу передать из useState в другую переменную
const [img, setImg] = useState(""); //от сюда надо предать img

const handleInputChange = (event) => {
  console.log("event", event.target.files);
  setData({ ...data, loading: true });
  img = event.target.files[0];//здесь принять его
  const info = new FormData();
  info.append("file", img);
  axios.post("http://localhost:3001/uploadImage/", info, {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
  });
};

выдаёт ошибку
   ╭─[C:\proj\test-project\src\components\FormCreateProduct\FormCreateProduct.jsx:11:1]
11 │ loading: false,
12 │ });
13 │
14 │ const [img, setImg] = useState("");
   · ─┬─
   ·  ╰── const variable was declared here
15 │ const handleInputChange = (event) => {
16 │ console.log("event", event.target.files);
17 │ setData({ ...data, loading: true });
18 │ img = event.target.files[0];
   · ─┬─
   ·  ╰── cannot reassign
19 │


выдаёт ошибку
cannot reassign to a variable declared with const
╭─[C:\proj\test-project\src\components\FormCreateProduct\FormCreateProduct.jsx:11:1]
11 │     loading: false,
12 │   });
13 │
14 │   const [img, setImg] = useState("");
·          ─┬─
·           ╰── const variable was declared here
15 │   const handleInputChange = (event) => {
16 │     console.log("event", event.target.files);
17 │     setData({ ...data, loading: true });
18 │     img = event.target.files[0];
·     ─┬─
·      ╰── cannot reassign
19 │

дополнить вопрос можно, нажав [edit]

@aleksandrbarakin дополнил


Ты пытаешься в const перезаписать значение, о чем ошибка тебе и говорит:

cannot reassign to a variable declared with const.

const [img, setImg]


Если ты хочешь обновить состояние, надо использовать его функцию, в данном случае у тебя setImg:
setImg(event.target.files[0])




Это не всё, что надо сделать.

Что я ещё забыл? Вроде, исходя из вопроса, максимально доступно объяснил, почему нельзя ничего записать в img

А что в твоём варианте в этой строчке добавится в форму? info.append("file", img); Очень подозреваю, ему стейт вообще не нужен, а если и нужен, то эту строчку надо править.

А следующий косяк тут: "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", хотя, это уже к вопросу не относится.

Ну если идти дальше, то да, в стейт запишется ни разу не изображение, надо будет ещё преобразовать в DataURL. А насчёт content-type я даже внимание не обратил)

Data url точно не надо. Они и так хорошо отработает, если вместо img = завести локальную переменную.
